# How does Vue.js distinguish router-views "looks like" in the same page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm refactoring web site using Vue.js (while learning vue.js).
My Vue2 project is created by 'vue init webpack my-project'.

**Business Logic:**

'index' page provides button to jump to 'signin' page, and 'signin' can jump back after submit. In my opinion, there should be a upper page which contains  to switch between 'index' and 'signin'. Call this  as 'view1'.

'index' has a navigation bar which switch 'page1' and 'page2' in content area. In my opinion, 'index' should contains  in its . Call this  as 'view2'.

As 'page1' display, it has a side-bar to show 'content1' and 'content2'. So another  called 'view3' is involved.

**Expection**

1. switch 'index' and 'signin' on 'view1' area
2. switch 'page1' and 'page2' on 'view2' area
3. switch 'content1' and 'content2' on 'view3' area

**Question**

Area region: view1>view2>view3. When 'content2' displays, view1 and view2 and view3 should both *enalbed*
I read normal router and embedded router and named router but have no design yet. I can't understand how
  this.$router.push('/index/page2')
could tell 'view2' to switch to 'page2' instead of tell 'view1' or 'view3' to do something. Or maybe I should use some other method to direct between views?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It seems children components bind to the child router-view only, at least  works (example: jsfiddle.net/keag65tw). I'll try $router.push later.